# What does the error "r8188eu not depends mac80211" mean?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

So I am trying to create a homemade Nintendo 3DS street pass relay using a script that uses Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I found at:

https://gbatemp.net/threads/how-to-have-a-homemade-streetpass-relay.352645/

So when I go and execute the script, I see 2 things happen,

1) PCI (sysfs) shows up for a couple of seconds and,

2) the error "r8188eu not depends mac80211"

I am running 14.04 on VMware and using a TP-Link TL-WN725N wireless adapter. I currently have no issues accessing the internet with this adapter and my router can see it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that you need a specially **patched** version of *hostapd* to run with *rtl8188eu* driver.

You can use the one at https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

```
sudo apt-get remove hostapd
sudo apt-get install git
cd /tmp
git clone git@github.com:lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
cd rtl8188eu/hostapd-0.8/hostapd
cp defconfig .config
make
sudo make install
```

If it still doesn't work, you need to add the following line in `/etc/hostapd.conf` or `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

```
driver=rtl871xdrv
```